# what is the correct way to filter data from db in monthly and yearly basis for analytics?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am making an analytics section for my client, where I need to display data in graphical form. For this I am using chart js. Now I have a model to store visitors of the website. Now I want to filter the data in monthly and yearly basis to put it in chart js and display it graphically.
Now what I am doing is this

```
monthly_visitor = VisitorCount.objects.all().filter(date_of_record__month = today.month).count()

yearly_visitor = VisitorCount.objects.all().filter(date_of_record__year = today.year).count()
```

Here, I am able to get the count for my current month and year. But making variables for each month and year is not the right to do it.

So please suggest me what is the correct procedure to filter the data so that I can make the analytics. I have never before done this, so I do no the correct approach, please suggest me.

Also the chart js code looks like this, which also perhaps no the correct way to do make the analytics

```
const vismonth = document.getElementById('visitorMonthly').getContext('2d');
const visitorMonthly = new Chart(vismonth, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Visitors Monthly',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }
    }
});

const visyear = document.getElementById('visitorYearly').getContext('2d');
const visitorYearly = new Chart(visyear, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['2022', '2023', '2024', '2025', '2026', '2027'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Visitors Yearly',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Please suggest me what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `annotate` in django.

```
from django.db.models import Count

monthly_visitor = VisitorCount.objects.all().values(
    'date_of_record__month'
    ).annotate(
        total_in_month=Count('id') # take visitor_id or whatever you want to count
        ).order_by()
```

it will give you queryset something like.

```
<QuerySet [{'created_at__month': 1, 'total_in_month': 5458}, {'created_at__month': 2, 'total_in_month': 4555}]
```

Comment: The Count('id) here shows Count name is undefined. How are yiu defining it to count the id

Comment: @RitankarBhattacharjee as I have mentioned instead of `id` put what you would like to count.

Comment: Yes Sir, i got that but the error I am getting is it says "name Count is undefined" so I am asking how are you defining the variable Count

Comment: ohh my bad, editing the code

Comment: @RitankarBhattacharjee i have added the code, now the ```Count``` is imported

Comment: Thank you so much , I was going through the documentation but they too did not mention about the import, thaank you so much